# Not getting form_for errors for required fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a form that when submitted runs a sidekiq worker.  Currently if you click submit on the empty form it attempts to run the worker.  Whhat I want is for it to alert the user that the fields need to me required before being submitted.

I have tried adding `:required => true` to the form fields, but that doesnt work. Also I cannot add in validations in the model.  What else could I do?

form

```
<%= form_for @call, :url => {:action => 'call_score_range'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :enter_score_range_one %>
  <%= f.number_field :score_range_one %>

  <%= f.label :enter_score_range_two %>
  <%= f.number_field :score_range_two %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing I can think of (without seeing your code) would be to add logic to the controller action (`:call_score_range` ?) to check for the presence of those fields manually, and add messages to the model there, bypassing the sidekiq logic.

```
def call_score_range
  @call = Call.new(params[:call])
  if @call.enter_score_range_one.present? && @call.enter_score_range_two.present?
    # Do sidekiq stuff
  else
    errors = []
    unless @call.enter_score_range_one.present?
      errors << 'Please enter score range one.'
    end
    unless @call.enter_score_range_two.present?
      errors << 'Please enter score range two.'
    end
    flash.now(errors)
    respond_with(@call)
  end
end
```